Answering Questions on Stack Law Exchange
Joe is a hypothetical person who thinks he knows something about the law but he has not gone to law school. He realizes that he does not know enough to give legal advice. He does not claim to be a lawyer.
Paul, a hypothetical person, is looking for good information about the law for an important decision he is going to make. Paul posts a question about the Law Stack Exchange and Joe answer's it. Joe's answer is factual in nature and would not constitute legal advice. Paul then relies on Joe's answer. Joe's answer is all wrong. Does Paul have any legal recourse against Joe?

One of the first rules of the internet is not to trust random people on it for many things including legal advice.

Joe is not a fireman.  Paul goes on the internet and asks how to put out a grease fire, Joe suggests dowsing it with gasoline.  Without any further research Paul does just that and is horribly burned...  Where does personal responsibility begin and end is really your question, right?

So what do the T&C of the LAW.SE site state about information posted on it?  Because Paul agreed to those T&Cs in order to post a question.

Paul doesn't have any recourse against Joe, as some weirdo on the internet who doesn't even claim to be a lawyer, much less his lawyer, is just some weirdo on the internet.  Paul listens to weirdos on the internet at his own risk.
If Paul needs legal advice about his own personal situation, he should pay a lawyer.  Or find one locally who might offer a free consultation.

Probably not.
california
In California, there's a prohibition on practicing law without license. However, the California statute doesn't actually define what "practicing law" actually is. Some things are allowed to non-attorneys: tax preparation and tax advice (CPAs, EAs, or CTPs), immigration assistance, navigating ACA, as examples. Here's an LA Bar article on the complexities of the matter. For tax matters, the Federal Circular 230 defines services as something a provider is compensated for.
However, practicing without license requires providing legal services, and it was held that that must not be something that unlicensed individual can and does routinely do. Shitposting on the Internet is something that unlicensed individuals can and routinely do engage in. As such I find it hard to believe that any judge would hold a random anonymous post written for free on a random website to be "legal services".

the practice of law will be described in terms of a lawyer’s typical functions - representing a client before a tribunal, giving legal advice, or drafting legal documents.

A random anonymous post on the Internet is neither of these things. As such reliance on such posts cannot be considered reliance on professional advice, and there would be no liability if that reliance leads to adverse effects.

The Help Center of Law.SE specifically says:

Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.

So you shouldn't ask such questions in the first place. And you've been clearly warned that you should not act on the answers as if they're real legal advice. If you choose to do so anyway, that's your own problem; the people posting advice believe that they have no legal liability.
If you feel this policy is wrong and should be changed, the appropriate place to raise this discussion would be Law.Meta
